# Is it possible to host an audio recorder and editor on a web application? How?

Tags: php, html, audio, audio-recording

Basically I have a web application made with PHP that allows users to publish short audio clips from their desktop to my server. As an added feature, I would like to create a recording platform that allows users to:

1. Record their audio
2. Apply voice filters (from an existing library)
3. Apply background audio (from an existing library)

The resulting audio is then tagged with certain descriptions and is uploaded to the server.

I'm unsure how to go about doing this, and my searches for existing libraries to do this have come up empty. Could I maybe use an open-source project like Audacity for this? I'm unfamiliar with how to determine what project can be used as an online web application and what projects can only exist as a desktop application.

Comment: How much are you paying us for it? This is not a freelancer website. Please read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before before posting any further questions.

Comment: I'm just looking for a point in the right direction... maybe a library to read about or a specific area or term that I should be researching. I'm not looking for a breakdown or step-by-step tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some references but I am no expert in audio field so they might not do everything you might require.

- [webaudiox.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/webaudiox)
- [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js)
- [pedalboard.js](https://github.com/dashersw/pedalboard.js)
- [wad](https://github.com/rserota/wad)
- [fifer.js](https://github.com/f5io/fifer-js)
- [html5-audio-editor](https://github.com/plucked/html5-audio-editor)

Anyways, it took me a simple google search to yield these libraries, so please learn to research and discover on your own.

Comment: Been a while since I posted this... ended up using the WebAudioAPI and the recording platform turned out exactly the way I wanted. Thanks for the tip!